# I think I am trying but is it good enough?

Tags: freelancing, employees

I graduated from university less than six months ago, though I consider myself to really be self-taught.  Even after getting my current job as a web developer, my company didn't offer any training as they expected me to be a guru and be able to handle anything they threw at me. I am not keeping up.  I haven't been able to learn everything that they need me to know as fast as they want me to know it.

My employer says they want someone who can handle many areas and help the development team more. I am willing, but it just seems like I either don't have the brains or haven't learned enough to work with these guys.

The company is considering hiring another web developer but I feel bad, as though I have not tried enough or was not good enough for them to keep me. My boss has not confirmed this, and has even said some complimentary things, like saying that they may not be able to find anyone as enthusiastic as I am. I think he's just being nice.

I also do a lot of freelancing on the side, which prevents me from having time to read books for which I don't have immediate need.

How can I learn... everything... in a very short time without being distracted and staying focused?

Comment: So you indicate that you don't know enough and that you can't keep up with the pace they expect of you, only to say at the end that you're also doing a lot of freelancing which prevents you from learning new things. It seems to me the answer is extremely straightforward then.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel ... well, working in a company is very different from freelancing. There are certain expectation from me that needs to align with the company's requirement unlike the freelance projects I get where most of it is based on what the clients has already seen from my portfolio that I can do - pretty much straight forward. It really has nothing to do with me learning, I'm just trying to find a way to get better. Also, as my company did not provide training - freelancing was the only way for me to learn and practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key phrases from the question: you graduated from University less than six months ago, and you're not keeping up in your new job.

Well, that's pretty normal. **When you start a new job, you need a period of time to get used to the way things work.** That includes the technical side, the company's business processes, the people, etc. You need this time even if you are familiar with the technology, and you need more if you are still learning the technology. For a fresh graduate I think that taking around 6 months to become productive is pretty normal (your mileage may vary), and it can take a year or more until you're proficient with the technologies.

**Every job will require you to adjust both in terms of technical skills** (every job you work on will require you to learn something you haven't used before) **and soft skills** (the people, procedures etc that are different in every company). In subsequent jobs the amount of time you'll need to become productive and learn technology will decrease because you'll be able to draw from your previous experiences. And the amount of time required to get used to the company itself will decrease as well because you'll learn to adapt more quickly.

When you're at the beginning, **the important thing is that you persist**. Don't panic and give up. There are three things that will help you become more comfortable in time:

- **Experienced colleagues**. If you can ask more senior colleagues for guidance whenever you run into a road block, it will save you hours of trial and error. However, don't overuse this privilege; ask them only after having made a reasonable attempt at solving the problem and researching yourself (see next point).
- **Research**. On the internet you'll find quick solutions to many problems (e.g. on Stack Overflow), and even guidance on how to tackle the more intricate ones. If you can find a good ready-made solution, you'll save time in development (because someone else did it before you), in testing and optimisation (because that someone else hopefully tested it pretty rigorously and is using it in a production environment) and in bothering your more experienced colleagues. Doing research is in fact the key to being a robust, independent developer because it gives you the ability to do work even when you don't know the technology in detail. Effective research is an important skill that you'll refine over time, so it's best to work on it as early as possible.
- **Your boss**. Depending on your relationship with your boss, you may be able to raise your concerns with him/her. It may only be your impression that you're not keeping up; if you have a good boss, then he will most likely have managed several people like you and he/she will know how long it takes for a new developer to become productive. In that respect your boss has a much wider vision than what you are currently seeing on an individual level, so your seeking your boss's advice is the best way to find out where you really stand. And it's good to clear this up as quickly as possible because if there really is a problem, then delaying this feedback for several months will do more harm than good.

Finally, I just wanted to address this point you mentioned:

> I also do a lot of freelancing on the side, which prevents me from having time to read books for which I don't have immediate need.

I'm obviously not going to tell you whether you should be freelancing or not.

However I know from experience that **it's important to leave time to read and learn new technology in your own time**, especially when you're still starting out. If you don't, then it will take you much longer to learn what you need.

**There is no way to "learn... everything... in a very short time". Learning takes time.** And the dilemma you're facing is a typical tradeoff. Freelancing will get you more money, and some experience, but will limit your overall learning, and thus your growth as a developer. Ultimately it's up to you to decide what's more important to you, but you can't have everything at once. That's something I learned the hard way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate your feedback. I actually joined the company to learn more from experience but as there was no training, personal projects was what keep me growing. I agree I need to find time to read more books and practice at the same time. I have personally concluded that I am not good enough for the position and perhaps not fitting in. I also have learnt 1 or 2 things which will help me better in my future employment. The good thing is, I already got an offer but scared the same thing might repeat itself.

Comment: These decisions are up to you, but whatever path you take, give yourself time. It's always hard in the beginning, but it gets better if you persevere. Changing jobs isn't a bad idea... it gives you breadth of experience. Just don't do it too often. First because it won't look good on you - employers will think that you don't manage to stick around. And second because you wouldn't have learned much. As I said, you need at least six months to become productive; if you leave before that, then you wouldn't have done enough to learn or to talk about at your next interview.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that web development has a lot of skills and technologies associated with it.  It's also true that not every "web developer" role is created equal - one group may need front end skills as the site is largely static, another may need everything from a full dynamic web stack, to skills with load balancing and security.

Chances are good that this was a mismatch in the position where they didn't understand the differences between your skills and their needs and vice-versa.  Most knowledge working positions will assume that you'll be able to pick up new technologies and skills on the job, but a wise employer will also realize that just about anyone will not be able to pick up an entirely new subject domain in 6 months.

Things to think about on the next position:

- Do reflect all the skills you know on your resume, but in giving a description of yourself, be ready to be honest about how much you know and what kind of work you've done.  It's very difficult to rate yourself as a novice/intermediate/expert, so instead mention what kind of work you've done "I worked with this for X months doing A, B and C"
- Do ask about what's expected in terms of on the job learning?  What kind of support does the company provide and what must you do yourself?
- Do ask about their technology stack.  You can expect that if you're missing 50% or more of the technologies in the list, you'll be really struggling for quite a while.  That doesn't mean don't take the job if offered, but be aware.
- Do pay attention to optimizing your time when you are learning.  The really great developers I know do this - they know how they learn best - some love a good wiki, some buy a book, some play with examples, some pair program with a friend, etc, etc.  Develop the learning structure that works best for you, and also keep track of how hard or easy it is for you to learn.  I know folks (for example) who are dyslexic, so not only do they enjoy non-printed material more than written stuff, but they plan extra time when they must read a document, knowing how frustrating it will be.
- Don't be ashamed to be honest about what it will take when giving estimates - it is far better to get the estimate right, than to promise a schedule you can't possibly meet.

Companies will vary wildly in the tradeoffs they are willing to make.  One may have a "grow your own model" of hiring people with little experience, because they can get these folks at a much lower cost.  Another will pay more and expect more - both in the technology stack and in the ability to execute efficiently and wisely.